# jQuery remove() doesn't remove

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I would like to allow users to add any number of fields to then insert the information they give me into a database. If there are any rows that are not used they can delete them by clicking the remove text so that I don't have a bunch of empty lines in my database.

I have accomplished the adding rows with jQuery and inserting the data into the database, but I am struggling with removing the unwanted rows. When jQuery runs the remove() function, it just gives the tr a display of none making it so that the user cannot see the rows but they still exist and insert blank lines into my database. Is there a way to totally get rid of the whole row in my table so that blank data cannot be entered?

Here is my code:

**Html:**

```
<table width="960px" border="0" id="entries">
<tr>
  <td><b></b></td>
  <td><b>Department</b></td>
  <td><b>Class</b></td>
  <td><b>Lot #</b></td>
  <td><b>Short Description</b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><b>1</b></td>
  <td class="firstEntry"><input type="text" name="fields[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="class[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="lot[]" size="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="description[]" size="86"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

```
<div id="container">
<p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>Add Entries.....</span></a></p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){

        count +=1;

    $('table#entries').append(
        '<tr><td><strong>' + count + '</strong></td>' + 
        '<td><input id="department_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input id="class_' + count + '" name="class[]' + '" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input id="lot_' + count + '" name="lot[]' + '" type="text" size="5"/></td>' +
        '<td><input id="description_' + count + '" name="description[]' + '" type="text" size="86"/></td>' +
        '<td><span class="delete">Remove</span></td></tr>' );

     $(".delete").click(function () {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove("slow");
    });

    });



});
```

Comment: remove cannot take slow as a param. remove is the correct method and will do exactly what you want if used correctly. if you want to define a speed at which it is visually removed try using fadeOut('slow') and then remove it once it is gone. http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: you have to make to two events in your one that fades the part out and one that does the remove

Answer (score 2):

It works without the "slow":

```
    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kn3eB/

The argument to [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is a selector. You might be thinking of [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) which takes a duration speed.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the jquery code from your jsfiddle into my original and it works now. I am not sure what I had wrong in my code, but it works... Thank you everyone very much for the answer and quick response!

Answer (score 2):

[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) doesn't take an animation effect as a parameter, only a selector. Perhaps you're confusing it with [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) which changes the opacity and display properties?

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7MjKR/1/)**

```
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(function () {
    $(this).remove()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have removed the slow, but it still gives the tr a display of none. Here is a screen shot of what I am getting...

http://cachecounty.org/assets/jquery-remove.PNG